# Log metrics in Springboot applicaiton using LoggingMeterRegistry

Tags: spring-boot, logging, metrics, spring-micrometer, codahale-metrics

I have some metrics being created in my springboot application and want to log the details of the metrics in a specific format as below:
2018-07-06 17:00:28,884 [metrics-logger-reporter-thread-1] [INFO] (com.codahale.metrics.Slf4jReporter) type=METER, name=io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.async-timeouts, count=0, mean_rate=0.0, m1=0.0, m5=0.0, m15=0.0, rate_unit=events/second

I'm currently using LoggingMeterRegistry to log my metrics but the format they get printed it is:system.cpu.usage{} value=0.041922","logger_name":"io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry"

I know that the required format can be achieved through codahale.dropwizard metrics but i want the same using LoggingMeterRegistry from "micrometer" since thats what i am using to calculate my other metrics.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

While asking an own question regarding `LoggingMeterRegistry` I got suggested this one, which neither helped me nor was answered. So I will try to answer it for future searches.

In order to customize the format of metric logging one could extends `LoggingMeterRegistry` and override the `publish()` method. There all meters can retrieved, iterated over, formatted then published. Below is a variant of how it could be done. Of course one could choose to publish all meters at once in which case formatting should be done first, then publishin last.

```
public class CustomLoggingMeterRegistry extends LoggingMeterRegistry {

  private final LoggingRegistryConfig config;
  private final Consumer<String> loggingSink;

  public CustomLoggingMeterRegistry(
      @NotNull LoggingRegistryConfig config,
      @NotNull Consumer<String> loggingSink) {
    super(Objects.requireNonNull(config),
        Clock.SYSTEM,
        Objects.requireNonNull(loggingSink));
    this.config = config;
    this.loggingSink = loggingSink;
  }


  @Override
  protected void publish() {
    if (config.enabled()) {
      getMeters()
          .stream()
          .sorted(Comparator
              .comparing((Meter m) -> m.getId().getType())
              .thenComparing(m -> m.getId().getName()))
          .forEach(meter -> meter.use(
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish,
              this::formatAndPublish));
    }
  }

  private void formatAndPublish(Meter otherMeter) {
    String formatterd = "// TODO format otherMeter as desired";
    this.loggingSink.accept(formatterd);
  }

  // A formatAndPublish for each Meter concrete type ...

}
```